# What is the best way to import demo data in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I've installed a theme in WordPress that needs to import demo data. I'm using the Import Demo Data. It's supposed to install "in a few minutes", but it looks like its taking forever

Is there any way to install the demo data?

Comment: You mean like a dummy data or that specific theme data?

Comment: Read the instructions, there may be minimum server requirements to import. Some of the instructions include disabling all plugins before you try to import. Without more info in your question it's hard to say. Most hosts allow you to increase these limits via your panel and editing the php.ini

Comment: I'm now working on my local data. From there, I'll try to import and migrate to the server